# Rename files according to list

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to rename files in a directory using a list. My code so far will only rename the first file before giving me a FileNotFoundError. How can I read the list and rename my files in the same order as it?

```
import os
import glob

fileLib = ('/filepath1/')
ref = ('/filepath2/ref.csv')

for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(fileLib, '*.csv')):
    with open(ref) as list1:
        line = list1.read().split(',\n')
        for name in line:
            os.rename(file, os.path.join(fileLib, '{}.csv'.format(name)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're applying the rename to the same file, since the loops are nested.

So the first time it works, and the next time it tries to rename a file that has been already renamed.

Reorganize your code. First, read the new names file:

```
fileLib = '/filepath1/'
ref = '/filepath2/ref.csv'

with open(ref) as list1:
    newnames = list1.read().split(',\n')
```

then `zip` directory contents and the new names list together with a single loop:

```
for file,newname in zip(glob.glob(os.path.join(fileLib, '*.csv')),newnames):
     os.rename(file, os.path.join(fileLib, '{}.csv'.format(newname)))
```

Since `zip` stops when one of the iterable parameters is exhausted, if the `glob` result is longer than the new names list, renaming will be done only partially, so it would be better to check that both lists have the same size prior to renamining.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to the zip thing, I couldn't figure out earlier how to order it so it would work but this works well.